# Connections closed in Live Migration State

Tags: google-compute-engine

Can Google Compute Engine's Live Migration cause the Memcached connections to be closed on the machine it happens? When checking the connection count,it dropped to 0 after that incident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you experience a small downtime due to a Live migration depending on what trigger the migration. The most common reason is a Host Error.

From the [Live Migration](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration) documentation "Failed hardware such as memory, CPU, network interface cards, disks, power, and so on. **This is done on a best-effort basis; if a hardware fails completely or otherwise prevents live migration, the VM crashes and restarts automatically and a [hostError](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#hosterror) is logged.**"

If your service is really sensitive about this I recommend you to use a [Managed Instance Group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/)